# find and replace Â£ to £

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, replace, find

Ive looked through a few search and replace functions but I cannot find a suitable one for finding "Â£" to "£".

I know this may be a 'Charset' issue but I'm looking for a JS soltion.

so in my HTML looks like this...

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Find &amp; Replace</title>
<style>
body {padding:100px; font:13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
Black Pants
<br />
<br />
Â£10.00 Â£15.00
</body>
</html>
```

This was caused by inserting a Looped Slider [found here](http://www.raymondselda.com/jquery-looped-slider-tutorial/) into the page, there was no extra character before hand. Has anyone else had this problem? if not does anyone have a simple solution to delete the character?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Yes, this is a charset issue and you *do not want to* solve it via JavaScript. Where do those prices come from?

Comment: + for the "you do not want to solve it via JavaScript". This is a problem of the code generating the pound symbol. Better way would be to make it generate &pound; instead of the symbol, and make the browser generate it..

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp for the entities reference